# Select UI items on Start

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity 5, and I have a UI panel with buttons. Attached to this panel is a script doing this

```
private List<Selectable> selectableItems;
void OnEnable()
{
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(selectableItems[0]);
}
```

After hitting the 'Play' button it does not get selected (color is still normal, not highlighted). What is causing that? EventSystem has this button as current selected objects and it is reacts on Submit.

Comment: This is shoot to the Moon, but I bet you're having Execution order problem. Make sure that the `selectableItems` have objects in it. BEFORE, calling the OnEnable(). Since OnEnable get executed BEFORE Start(). I suggest you put your instantiation of list in the Awake() method.

Comment: What input module are you using?

Comment: I am using standalone input module. Also I noticed that if I put `EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(...)` in Update function, item will not be selected until I click on screen first.

Comment: filling `selectableItems` in Awake functions does nothing.